# How to log incoming messages in apache beam pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam-io

I am writing a simple apache beam streaming pipeline, taking input from a pubsub topic and storing this into bigquery. For hours I thought I am not able to even read a message, as I was simply trying to log the input to console:

```py
events = p | 'Read PubSub' >> ReadFromPubSub(subscription=SUBSCRIPTION)
logging.info(events)
```

When I write this to text it works fine! However my call to the `logger` never happens.

How to people develop / debug these streaming pipelines?

I have tried adding the following line:
`events | 'Log' >> logging.info(events)`

Using `print()` also yields no results in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `events` is a `PCollection` so you need to apply a [`PTransform`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#transforms) to it.

The simplest way would be to apply a `ParDo` to `events`:

```py
events | 'Log results' >> beam.ParDo(LogResults())
```

which is defined as:

```py
class LogResults(beam.DoFn):
  """Just log the results"""
  def process(self, element):
    logging.info("Pub/Sub event: %s", element)
    yield element
```

Notice that I also yield the element in case you want to apply further steps downstream, such as writing to a sink after logging the elements. See the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56153715/how-to-filter-none-values-out-of-pcollection/56182917#56182917), for example.

Comment: Whilst the logging works, strangely this converts the type from `str` to `int` - `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not int`

Comment: Can you edit the question with more context such as the log output and full code? Does the same happen with `yield` instead of `return`?

Comment: I am not going to edit the question, as this is an issue with the solution. `yield` works fine - any idea why?

I would say you should edit the solution.

Comment: Sure, if that fixed it then it's not necessary to add more details to the question. I have edited the answer accordingly. With `yield` a generator is returned

Comment: This seems to happen for any DoFn, if I use return the datatype changes... do you know the reason why?

Comment: You need to retun an iterable so you can use either `yield element` or `return [element]`. I made a quick test with all three cases and calling the logging function back to back. Code and results [here](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/933649b217ab29660502a105ddc8e892).

Answer (score 1):

A brief way of doing it without using Map is via [beam.LogElements()](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.transforms.util.html#apache_beam.transforms.util.LogElements) inbuilt logging transform.

So your code can become this,

```
 p | 'Read PubSub' >> ReadFromPubSub(subscription=SUBSCRIPTION) | beam.LogElements()
```