# Apache Beam on Python multiplies beam.Map calls

Tags: python, pipeline, apache-beam, dataflow, google-bigquery

I'm working on a pipeline with DataFlow which has to do the following:

- Extract from BigQuery last elaborated item (from 2 different paths)
- For every path get new Items via SFTP and save them into local file system
- Upload files to Google Cloud Storage

I have to get files locally because the pipeline doesn't run on DataFlow cluster (it's not the definitive code...).

From the BigQuery select I get two records:

[image]

I use these 2 outputs as inputs for the SFTP function (that download only 1 file for the path 1951, '1951_2019112215.log.gz', and no files for the path 1952) and then I return a dictionary with the name of the path and the downloaded files:

```
{'1951': ['1951_2019112215.log.gz']}
{'1952': []}
```

Now I call the function that uploads them to a GC bucket and I expect it to be called twice, once per input... but it is called 8 times (4 times per input) independently from the number of downloaded files.

Can you please explain me why and what I am missing?
This is the pipeline:

```
(p
    | 'Read Configuration Table ' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(config['ENVIRONMENT']['configuration_table'])) #output 2 records from BQ
    | 'Get Files from Server' >> beam.Map(import_file) #Download files from SFTP and returns the 2 dictionaries above, 1 per call
    | 'Upload files on Bucket' >> beam.Map(upload_file_on_bucket) #it is called 4 time per input
 )
```

with

```
def import_file(element):
    cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
    cnopts.hostkeys = None
    srv = pysftp.Connection(host=config['SFTP']['host'],
                            username=config['SFTP']['username'],
                            private_key=os.path.join('config', config['SFTP']['private_key']),
                            cnopts=cnopts)

    list_downloaded_files = []

    last = element['last_file']
    file_type = element['folder']

    if file_type == '1951':
        folder = config['SFTP']['folder_1951']
    else:
        folder = config['SFTP']['folder_1952']

    file_list = srv.listdir(folder)

    if len(file_list) > 0:
        file_list = file_list[file_list.index(last)+1:]

    for file in file_list:
        srv.get(remotepath=folder+'/'+str(file), # da cambiare quando gira sul cluster
                #remotepath=os.path.join(folder, str(file)),
                localpath=os.path.join('download', file))
        list_downloaded_files.append(str(file))

    return {file_type: list_downloaded_files}
```

and

```
def upload_file_on_bucket(list_of_files):
    print('chiamata')
    print(list_of_files)
    if '1951' in list_of_files:
        file_type = '1951'
        list_of_files = list_of_files['1951']
    else:
        file_type = '1952'
        list_of_files = list_of_files['1952']

    client = storage.Client(project='MYPROJECT')
    bucket = client.get_bucket('MYBUCKET')

    if len(list_of_files) > 0:
        for file in list_of_files:
            blob = bucket.blob('MYPATH' + file)
            blob.upload_from_filename(os.path.join('download', file))
            #os.remove(os.path.join('download', file))

    list_of_files.sort()
    print({file_type: list_of_files[-1]})
    return {file_type: list_of_files[-1]}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the implementations of the `import_file` and `upload_file_on_bucket` functions?

Comment: This can be happening if you use `return element` inside the `import_file` function. If so, use `return [element]` or `yield element` instead. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57482858/6121516) and [test](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/933649b217ab29660502a105ddc8e892).

Comment: Thanks to both and sorry for the late reply!
@manesioz I've just modified the problem with my code!

Comment: @GuillemXercavins correct, I use return! I'll try your example and I'll be back to you!

Comment: @GuillemXercavins thanks, using yields seems to work but I'm not sure to understand well how generators work! Can you provide me an example, please? thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear, I can add it as an answer if it helps. Regarding Beam-specific examples. you can refer to this test: https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/933649b217ab29660502a105ddc8e892 in which, when we use `return element` as output, the next ParDo receives two entries instead of one (and that's the reason I suspected this could be the cause). Of course, this is a more general Python concept and you can find resources on the topic such as this one: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-generators-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks @GuillemXercavins, it really helped me! I think you can add it as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function invocations can be duplicated if we return a dict instead of a list or a generator from the previous function. For this, we should use `return [element]` or `yield element` instead of `return element`. An example to showcase this with the following data:

```py
data = [{'team': 'red', 'score': 10},
            {'team': 'blue', 'score': 8}]
```

where we invoke the same `ParDo` back to back:

```py
events = (p
  | 'Create Events' >> beam.Create(data) \
  | 'Log results 1' >> beam.ParDo(LogResults())
  | 'Log results 2' >> beam.ParDo(LogResults()))
```

and we uncomment only one of the return/yield lines each time:

```py
class LogResults(beam.DoFn):
  """Just log the results"""
  def process(self, element):
    logging.info("Event: %s", element)

    # yield element  # option 1
    # return element  # option 2
    # return [element]  # option 3
```

and we compare the logging output for all three options:

```py
yield element
INFO:root:Event: {'score': 10, 'team': 'red'}
INFO:root:Event: {'score': 10, 'team': 'red'}
INFO:root:Event: {'score': 8, 'team': 'blue'}
INFO:root:Event: {'score': 8, 'team': 'blue'}

return element
INFO:root:Event: {'score': 10, 'team': 'red'}
INFO:root:Event: score
INFO:root:Event: team
INFO:root:Event: {'score': 8, 'team': 'blue'}
INFO:root:Event: score
INFO:root:Event: team

return [element]
INFO:root:Event: {'score': 10, 'team': 'red'}
INFO:root:Event: {'score': 10, 'team': 'red'}
INFO:root:Event: {'score': 8, 'team': 'blue'}
INFO:root:Event: {'score': 8, 'team': 'blue'}
```

`LogResults` will be called twice (once for each dictionary key) when we use `return element`.